# How can I hide the input accessory view of the keyboard when using a WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview

We have a webview in our app to edit some text in a semi-wysiwyg style. It's just a fullscreen text area so we don't want those next/previous/done buttons on the keyboard taking in precious screen space. Previously, the following worked to remove the whole bar where those buttons are shown:

```
-(void)__removeInputAccessoryView {
    UIView* subview;

    for (UIView* view in _editorView.scrollView.subviews) {
        if([[view.class description] hasPrefix:@"UIWeb"])
            subview = view;
    }

    if(subview == nil) {
        return;
    }

    NSString* name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@RWWebviewHelper", subview.class.superclass];
    Class newClass = NSClassFromString(name);

    if(newClass == nil) {
        newClass = objc_allocateClassPair(subview.class, [name cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], 0);
        if(!newClass) {
            return;
        }

        Method method = class_getInstanceMethod([RWWebviewHelper class], @selector(inputAccessoryView));
        class_addMethod(newClass, @selector(inputAccessoryView), method_getImplementation(method), method_getTypeEncoding(method));

        objc_registerClassPair(newClass);
    }

    object_setClass(subview, newClass);
}
```

I found similar snippets on SO and Github, both in Objective-C and Swift. I'm currently converting this class from Objective-C to Swift *and* from using UIWebView to using a WKWebView. I found this on SO somewhere:

```
private func removeInputAccessoryView() {
    final class FauxBarHelper: NSObject {
        var inputAccessoryView: AnyObject? { return nil }
    }

    editorView.scrollView.subviews.forEach { view in
        if String(describing: type(of: view)).hasPrefix("WKcon") {
            let noInputAccessoryViewClassName = "\(view.superclass!)_NoInputAccessoryView"
            var newClass: AnyClass? = NSClassFromString(noInputAccessoryViewClassName)
            if newClass == nil {
                let targetClass: AnyClass = object_getClass(view)
                newClass = objc_allocateClassPair(targetClass, noInputAccessoryViewClassName.cString(using: String.Encoding.ascii)!, 0)
            }

            let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(FauxBarHelper.self, #selector(getter: FauxBarHelper.inputAccessoryView))
            class_addMethod(newClass!.self, #selector(getter: FauxBarHelper.inputAccessoryView), method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
            object_setClass(view, newClass)
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't hide the bar. I'm not too well versed in hacking the private API and after playing around with the values in that snippet I can't find a way to hide the bar. I know this is a store rejection risk, but you know how clients are. I need to get this working. I can work with an Objective-C snippet, but prefer Swift.

Does anyone have an idea? I feel it shouldn't be very hard to hide a button bar from an onscreen keyboard, am I missing something simple?